# Color Grading in Adobe premiere elements

Tags: premiere, color-grading, premiere-elements

I recently started to film with my drone(phantom 4). I read somewhere that it was recommended to use some "flat" preset, like D-Log or D-cinelike, which I did.

Now I've very flat video, and I've some hard time to find how I can easily restore the color back on adobe premiere elements(which I'm using over adobe premiere pro because of the dynamic titles).

Can someone explain how to restore the colors easily?

I found severals things(tridirectional color corrector), but I can't find how to bring nice colors back.

I was able to do such things with Adobe lightroom for pictures, by adjusting the histogram to have it filling the whole spectrum, adjusting low/light, saturation and that's it, but here I cannot find how to do it?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to use 3 way color corrector.

Do a first pass color correction to get it to a standard look.

Then do a 2nd pass within the same filter (lower down on the filter) to grade.

Or get Resolve (paid version), or Color Finesse, which is also very good.

Comment: Hi, I just saw the lumetri effect, which seems to be a much easier way of doing things. Is there something that I can not do with it but with the 3 way color corrector? About resolve, what is the difference between the paid and free version? Do you still use adobe premiere or not at all?

Comment: The 3 Way Color Corrector will accomplish what you are trying to do, without using a X-Rite, color cards, or resolve. You need to read up on basic color correction, and then grading. They are two separate passes on your video. You first want to get your video to what you would consider "base". Meaning- this is how it should look with video. Then you can grade. The codec from the GoPro is limited, as it's compression is I believe 4:2:0, so theres only so much room to grade. But - the easiest way to get a decent image:  Increase Contrast. Increase Saturation. Then Apply an S-Curve.

Comment: Read up on adding an S-Curve to your video footage using the curves effect. You can add the curve to the master channel or any of the RGB channels respectively. But it's more than I can type here, and there are many videos online on youtube, and google, if you just search S-Curve Video Premiere. You'll find plenty of how-to pages on how its done. The video out of the go-pro is flat for a reason. The reason it's flat is so the blacks arent crushed and the highlights arent blown out. The limited gamut allows you to expand it to your taste in post.

Comment: Thank you very much. But can you just tell me the difference between the lumetri and the 3 way corrector? For me it seems the result could be the same, only the way to do it was different? (Ps, with my Phantom 4, it's not a GoPro but a Phantom camera(sony I think).

Comment: Im honestly not familiar with lumetri... Heres a very very down and dirty CC I did to show how using just RGB curves, next, HSL, last Video Limiter, changes it from flat to descent. It could be much much better. I just grabbed the photo off the internet. But the curves, specifically the luma (white) and adding the S curve I added, will make your video pop. Hope this helps.   LINK TO ALBUM OF FILTERS AND BEFORE AFTER:  http://imgur.com/a/Gd0rD

Comment: Nice this helps me a lot. I've to take some lessons on how to do such things, but the issue with youtube video is that you have 10 different explanation for the same thing.What is the "Video Limiter"?